# How to do pairwise list matching in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I am working with the iris dataset, and I want to find the index (or just subset) of every value that have a certain Sepal.Width and Petal.Length.

```
Desired_Width = c(3.5, 3.2, 3.6)
Desired_Length = c(1.4, 1.3, 1.4)
```

I don't want to mix and match, like I would be if I did the following:

```
Desired_index = which(iris$Sepal.Width %in% Desired_Width &
                      iris$Petal.Length %in% Desired_Length)
```

I only want rows with Widths Desired_Width[ i ] and Lengths Desired_Length[ i ]

(That's rows 1, 3, and 5.)

I don't want to use a for loop, how would I do this using dplyr or 'which'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be using base R `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) which(iris$Sepal.Width == x & iris$Petal.Length == y),
                      Desired_Width, Desired_Length)


#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    5
#[2,]   18   43   38
```

Note that there are two rows in the output because there are two entries which satisfy the condition. For example, for first entry we can check row 1 and 18 have same `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Length` value.

```
iris[c(1, 18), ]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#18          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3  setosa
```

---

The same can be done using `map2` from `purrr`

```
purrr::map2(Desired_Width, Desired_Length, 
    ~which(iris$Sepal.Width == .x & iris$Petal.Length == .y))


#[[1]]
#[1]  1 18

#[[2]]
#[1]  3 43

#[[3]]
#[1]  5 38
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way from `merge`

```
mergedf=data.frame('Sepal.Length'=Desired_Length,'Sepal.Width'=Desired_Width)
yourdf=merge(iris,mergedf,by=c('Sepal.Width','Sepal.Length'),all.y =T)
```